# three.js: how do you rotate a mesh that has already been created?

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions

I would like to rotate a mesh by applying a quaternion.

The Vector3 prototype has a method named `applyQuaternion` ([api link](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion)), so one could in theory map this function over all the vertices of the geometry inside the mesh. Is this the way to do it?

Why don't the Mesh constructor have a function like `applyQuaternion`? That would make a lot of sense, to me at least.

Comment: Use applyQuaternion to transform the vector 3 then use lookAt to rotate the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, as a Mesh is based off an [Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) we see the applyMatrix method therein. Digging into the [Matrix](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Matrix4) we find a makeRotationFromQuaternion method. This chain should get the results you desire.